# AWS Pinpoint Send Email fails

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, email

I tried to follow [this guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/latest/developerguide/send-messages-sdk.html) to send emails using AWS Pinpoint.
I set my aws credentials in .aws/credentials.
I am having trouble creating objects for the PinPointClient, PinPointEmailClient interfaces. I followed the guide exactly. Added all the imports. But it would throw error every time.
This is my code:

```
{
   public void sendEmail ( AWSEmailIntegrationSettings 
 awsEmailIntegrationSettings, String 
     emailAddress,String emailSubject, String emailBody)  {

        Map mapResponse;
        String appId = awsEmailIntegrationSettings.pinpointApplicationID  ;
        String senderAddress = awsEmailIntegrationSettings.originationEmail;
        String toAddress =  emailAddress;
        String emailBodyHTML = "<h1>Hello , Test Email</h1>";
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
       
        SendMessagesRequest sendEmailRequest = null;
        SendMessagesRequest messagesRequest= null;

        try {
              PinpointClient mPinpointClient = PinpointClient.builder()
                .region(region)
                .build();

                Map<String,AddressConfiguration> addressMap = new HashMap<String,AddressConfiguration>();
                AddressConfiguration configuration =  AddressConfiguration.builder()
                        .channelType(ChannelType.EMAIL)
                        .build();

                addressMap.put(toAddress, configuration);
                SimpleEmailPart emailPart = SimpleEmailPart.builder()
                        .data(emailBodyHTML)
                        .charset(charset)
                        .build() ;

                SimpleEmailPart subjectPart = SimpleEmailPart.builder()
                        .data(emailSubject)
                        .charset(charset)
                        .build() ;

                SimpleEmail simpleEmail = SimpleEmail.builder()
                        .htmlPart(emailPart)
                        .subject(subjectPart)
                        .build();

                EmailMessage emailMessage =  EmailMessage.builder()
                        .body("Hello !")
                        .fromAddress(senderAddress)
                        .simpleEmail(simpleEmail)
                        .build();

                DirectMessageConfiguration directMessageConfiguration = DirectMessageConfiguration.builder()
                        .emailMessage(emailMessage)
                        .build();

                MessageRequest messageRequest = MessageRequest.builder()
                        .addresses(addressMap)
                        .messageConfiguration(directMessageConfiguration)
                        .build();

                messagesRequest = SendMessagesRequest.builder()
                        .applicationId(appId)
                        .messageRequest(messageRequest)
                        .build();

            mPinpointClient.sendMessages(messagesRequest);
           
            mLogger.info("Email was sent");
            mPinpointClient.close();


        } catch (Exception e) {

            mLogger.error("Send Email Failed [method:sendEmail] ",e);
            throw e;

        }

    }

}
```

```
When I run the code, I get an exception on this code :  
          PinpointClient mPinpointClient = PinpointClient.builder()
                .region(region)
                .build();
This is the exception :"java.lang.IllegalArgumentExcpetion : Expected a '=' sign when defining property on second line."
```

I would very much appreciate it, if someone can help me with this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tested this example and it works perfectly...

[image]

My email arrived too in my inbox.

First - the code in your Service client is not correct.

Region should be like this:

```
 PinpointClient pinpoint = PinpointClient.builder()
                .region(Region.US_EAST_1)
                .build();
```

or

```
 Region region = Region.US_EAST_1;
 PinpointClient pinpoint = PinpointClient.builder()
                    .region(region )
                    .build();
```

In your example, I do not see where region is set. Therefore it seems that you have not used **.region** correctly.

Did you add all of the POM dependencies to your POM file? See the POM file located in the Pinpoint V2 Github repo here:

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/example_code/pinpoint

Can you post your POM file that you are using.

For future reference - Pinpoint V2 code examples can be located in AWS Github repo here:

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/example_code/pinpoint/src/main/java/com/example/pinpoint

The Java v2 DEV guide that explains how to work with the AWS SDK for Java V2 is here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/get-started.html

Comment: Thank you @smac2020 . I made an error in credentials file. I used ' : ' instead of ' = ' for assigning values to the AWS Access Key and AWS Secret Key, Changing to ' = ' fixed the issue.